# The vue-form-generator github repo states it supports "custom styles". Where's the documentation?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

The [vue-form-generator](https://github.com/vue-generators/vue-form-generator) github repo states it supports "custom styles", "Bootstrap friendly templates", etc. I can't find any documentation on how to style vue-form-generator components. Is there doc anywhere? Am I missing something obvious? Note: I'm very new to Vue.js

Comment: "custom styles" === you can write your own CSS

Comment: Thanks - but how do I connect it to `vue-form-generator`? Do I have to just look at the source? I was hoping for some sort of guide. E.g. this component has this class, etc. Even some samples of custom styling - do they exist?

Comment: obviously this plugin uses bootstrap classes, i think "custom styles" means you can override these classes (like `form-group` `form-control` etc...)

Comment: "obviously this plugin uses bootstrap classes" - it wasn't obvious to me. I'll have a look at that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [document](https://icebob.gitbooks.io/vueformgenerator/content/fields/field_properties.html), you can add addition custom css class using `styleClasses` props:

```
{
    type: "input",
    inputType: "text",
    label: "Name",
    model: "name",
    maxlength: 50,
    required: true,
    placeholder: "User's full name",
    validator: validators.string,
    styleClasses: 'my-input-class'
}
```

Then custom css style classes will be appended to the `.form-group`

Comment: Thanks! That helps a lot. Very hidden from my point of view but now I know it.